# receiving GPS turned off when using fused location provider

Tags: android, android-location, fusedlocationproviderapi

I've registered to location updates using the fused location provider. How can I know if suddenly an error occurred? For example, I've turned the location off (after connection to the fused location provider). I haven't found a way to receive an error through the fused api, I just stop reviving location updates.

Comment: try this https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/GpsStatus.Listener.html

Comment: It's not part of the fused api

Comment: It is under a different name, GeoFencing.